# REGEX de HH:MM:SS podendo ser negativo

Tags: regex

Estou trabalhando com HH:MM:SS e tenho esse REGEX `^([0-1]?\\d{0,4})(?::([0-5]?\\d))?(?::([0-5]?\\d))?$` estou utilizando a biblioteca [InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) porém eu gostaria de trabalhar com horas negativas exemplo:

Esforço: -200:00:00

eu posso continuar usando esse regex ou tenho que utilizar outro?

Comment: Utilize `-?` para indicar que o hífen no início é opcional. `^-?(?:[0-9]{0,4}):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9])$`

Comment: Funcionou obrigado @ValdeirPsr

Comment: @ValdeirPsr agora só postar como resposta para ganhar o aceito :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilize  `-?`  no começo do REGEX para que o sinal de negativo seja opcional:

```
 ^-?(?:[0-9]{0,4}):(?:[0-5][0-9]):(?:[0-5][0-9])$
```